# Android - Reset Variables when App is Closing

Tags: android, events

I'm creating an Android App, 
in this app i have to cancel some data when the app is closing,
how i can do that?

There is some event like onDestroy?

Comment: ya, `onDestroy()` , `onPause()` and `onStop()` methods are there, check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: no, the application class has no callback for "when the app closes". That said on the android platform an app is pushed to the background e.g. when you hit the home button or get a phone call. You'd have to use workarounds to reset your variables "on app closing". (P.S. the notion of an app closing doesn't exist on android)

Comment: Ok, Thank you!

So i could make a splash screen that appear when the app i opening, and during the splash screen i can cancel my data.

I think that this way can be right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try override `onBackPressed` on your first activity it wont be a complete solutions though.